# Why are we interested in whether a given hitting time is a stopping time?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Why are we interested in whether a given hitting time $\tau_B=\inf\{t \geq 0\,|\, X(t) \in B\}$ of a stochastic process $\{X(t)\}_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is a stopping time,i.e. that $\{\tau_B \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}(t)$ holds for all $t$ (where $\{\mathcal{F}(t)\}_{t \in [0,\infty)}$ is the corresponding filtration)? If we use such a hitting time as a termination criterion (e.g. if the stock rises the first time above 200 dollars we sell) it would of course make sense to know at every time $t $ whether we have to terminate at this point. But then it would be enough to demand that $\{\tau_B=t\} \in \mathcal{F}(t)$ right?

Comment: Consider the betting strategy of doubling your bet when you lose and walking away when you win.

Comment: No: your decision criterion is whether you have won, and this will eventually happen in finite time with probability $1$.  The problem is that the expected time is infinite, so you lose some of the shortcuts about expectation.

Comment: @Henry In discrete time the expected time is infinite, but in continuous time it's not as clear how one would "double your bet when you lose" because the bets happen instantaneously.  There are similar strategies that can guarantee one increases their wealth in a bounded amount of time (e.g. by dividing up the interval $[0,T]$ into an infinite number of discrete intervals and following the doubling strategy at the end of each interval).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only requiring $\{\tau = t\} \in \mathcal F(t)$ for $\tau$ to be a stopping time is too weak.  We usually work with augmented filtrations satisfying the usual conditions, in particular we assume that $\mathcal F(t)$ contains all null-events of $\mathcal F_\infty$.  If $\tau$ is any continuous random variable with $\mathbb{P}(\{\tau = t\}) = 0$ for all $t$, then $\{\tau = t\} \in \mathcal F(t)$ for all $t$ so $\tau$ would be a stopping time under that definition.  We don't want that because it would include things like the *last* time that $X(t)$ reaches a certain level, or the time that $X(t)$ reaches its maximum on $[0,T]$ - both of those are things that we, intuitively, shouldn't know at the time that they happen and only be able to determine later.